# Change height of static UITableViewCell to fit content

Tags: ios, uitableview

Pretty much as the title says. I am looking at how to change the height of static UITableViewCell to fit content. So I have several static sections with 1 TableViewCell within each. The UILabels within are overflowing the UITableviewCell and I need it to fit.

[image]

What I'm struggling with:

- How to target static table cell (Is it the same as if dynamic? Use a reuse identifier? )
- How to resize the static table cell dynamically to fit the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

method of the `UITableViewDelegate`. It's the only way to programmatically calculate the height of the cell and return it to the table when the table needs to display it.

#### Example

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *string = @"Your string";
    
    CGRect boundingBox = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                              options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}
                                              context:nil];
    
    return CGRectGetHeight(boundingBox);
}
```

This solution is the cleanest and it works. The method above is part of the delegate protocol, which it seems can still be used to tweak the style and layout defined by the storyboard. However, Apple does not recommend it:

> If a table view in a storyboard is static, the custom subclass of
> UITableViewController that contains the table view should not
> implement the data source protocol. - [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)

So if you want to **dynamically** change attributes of the cell, use **dynamic** cells, not static.